# Problem with MySql INSERT MAX()+1

Tags: sql, mysql, insert, max, increment

I have a single table containing many users. In that table I have column called user_id (INT), which I want increment separately for each person. user_id MUST start at 1

I've prepared a simple example:

```
Showing all names
+--------------+-----------------------+
| user_id      | name                  |
+--------------+-----------------------+
| 1            | Bob                   |
| 1            | Marry                 |
| 2            | Bob                   |
| 1            | John                  |
| 3            | Bob                   |
| 2            | Marry                 |
+--------------+-----------------------+


Showing only where name = Bob
+--------------+-----------------------+
| user_id      | name                  |
+--------------+-----------------------+
| 1            | Bob                   |
| 2            | Bob                   |
| 3            | Bob                   |
+--------------+-----------------------+
```

The following query will do this, but it will only work if 'Bob' already exists in the table...

```
INSERT INTO users(user_id, name) SELECT(SELECT MAX(user_id)+1 from users where 
name='Bob'), 'Bob';
```

If Bob does not exist (first entry) user_id is set to 0 (zero). This is the problem. I need the user_id to start from 1 not 0.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
INSERT INTO users (user_id, name)
SELECT 1 + coalesce((SELECT max(user_id) FROM users WHERE name='Bob'), 0), 'Bob';
```

But such query can lead to a race condition. Make sure you are in a transaction and you lock the users table before running it. Otherwise you might end up with two Bobs with the same number.

Comment: Yes, the query works, but please don't ignore the second part. :) Or if you decide to ignore it, at least create an unique index on `(name, user_id)` so that the query that would otherwise produce a duplicate fails.

Comment: That was my next question actually, it's here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590648/mysql-innodb-locking-only-the-affected-rows

Answer (score 6):

You can use [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull):

```
INSERT INTO users(user_id, name)
SELECT(IFNULL((SELECT MAX(user_id)+1 from users where name='Bob'), 1), 'Bob';
```

Comment: looks like it would work but for some reason mysql throws a syntax error:

...syntax to use near 'SELECT MAX(user_id)+1 from users where name='Bob'),1), 'Bob'' at line 1

Comment: @Chad: Replace `IFNULL(` with `IFNULL((` and it will work, it's just unbalanced parentheses.

Comment: Yes, that's why it didn't work. I wonder which method is quicker/best.

Comment: Oops, fixed the missing bracket. There's very little difference between mine and @Lukas's answers - use whichever you find easier to read / understand.

Answer (score 3):

It's been [reported as a bug in MySQL](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=3575).

I'm quoting Guilhem Bichot:

> Second, here is the simplest of workarounds:
>   instead of using:
>   insert into foo(lfd) values((select max(lfd) from foo)+1)
>   just do
>   insert into foo(lfd) select (max(lfd)+1) from foo;

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Don't use MAX() + 1 then. Use an auto-numbering scheme on the table.</strike>

I didn't read the question properly. Use Greg's suggestion of IFNULL().

Comment: Won't an auto-numbering scheme on the table number each record sequentially, rather than making the first "Bob" 1 and the second "Bob" 2, and the first "Chad" 1 and then second "Chad" 2 and so on?

Comment: I didn't read the question properly. I'll defer to Greg's answer with IFNULL().