# MySQL InnoDB locking only the affected rows?

Tags: sql, mysql, innodb, rowlocking

I have an InnoDB table containing users, like this:

```
+--------------+-----------------------+
| user_id      | name                  |
+--------------+-----------------------+
| 1            | Bob                   |
| 1            | Marry                 |
| 2            | Bob                   |
| 1            | John                  |
| 3            | Bob                   |
| 2            | Marry                 |
+--------------+-----------------------+
```

On each insert I increment user_id by 1 so for example, the next user_id for Bob will be 4

I use this query to do that:

```
INSERT INTO users (user_id, name)
SELECT 1 + coalesce((SELECT max(user_id) FROM users WHERE name='Bob'), 0), 'Bob';
```

Now I need to make sure that two different users don't add a 'Bob' at the same time. I don't want any two Bobs with user_id 4. Each of Bob's user ids must be different.

Is is possible to write and update lock all of Bob's rows when the above insert query is run? I cannot lock the whole table because many other users still need full access to their rows. Also, all rows should be readable at all times. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming InnoDB here, you can use [SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) to lock the rows when you select them.

Comment: AFAIK LOCK IN SHARED MODE is not enough, you have to {{LOCK TABLE}} or make a uniq index and retry your update if it fails as @txyoji answer.

Answer (score 3):

To solve the first part of your question,
create a unique index on user_id and name.

```
alter table `users` add unique index ak_user_id_name(user_id,name);
```

That will prevent duplicate user_id,name records.

Comment: But there CAN be multiple 1's in user_id row but each will belong to a different user. Just like there can be multiple Bob's but each will have different user_id

Comment: This won't prevent that. 
Its a composite key made up of both user_id and name.
It prevents a duplicate user_id/name combination from being entered.
So 1/bob, 1/sue, 2/bob are ok. Putting in another 1/bob will cause a database error.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this question is the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694658/how-many-rows-will-be-locked-by-select-order-by-xxx-limit-1-for-update/5704927).  InnoDB will lock more rows here than you expect for safety with statement-based binary logging.

**The solution:** use row based binary logging with the read-committed isolation level.