# SELECT FOR UPDATE and WHERE condition on two indexed columns - what's locking strategy?

Tags: mysql, transactions, rowlocking

This question is a logical continuation of this one:

[How many rows will be locked by SELECT ... ORDER BY xxx LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694658/how-many-rows-will-be-locked-by-select-order-by-xxx-limit-1-for-update)

Suppose I have such SELECT:

```
SELECT id, status FROM job WHERE status = XXX AND id IN (1, 2, 3) FOR UPDATE
```

id is primary key, status is indexed.

What's MySQL locking strategy in this case?

1. Lock rows matching only both conditions
2. Lock all rows matching first condition + lock all rows matching the second condition separately
3. Lock the whole table

I think the most logical is 2. But... I'm not sure. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I made tests and they show that option 1 is in effect in this case.

> Lock rows matching only both
>   conditions