# MYSQL select for update locking more than expected number of rows because of Order by clause

Tags: mysql, locking

I will give a simple example to put forward the problem I am facing. Consider that there are two transactions trying to access some rows in a table using `select for update` clause as follows:-

**Transaction 1**-

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM maas.model_requests where id='test1' and model_request_status='QUEUED' order by priority asc limit 1 for update;
```

**Transaction 2** -

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM maas.model_requests where id='test2' and model_request_status='QUEUED' order by priority asc limit 1  for update;
COMMIT;
```

As you can see, both the transactions are trying to access different rows of table `model_requests` id in both the where clauses being different. Also, I have not committed first transaction so that examine if the select for update is locking more rows than expected. Result of above two transactions getting executed simultaneously is transaction 2 can never get lock even though transaction 1 is supposed to lock only row having `id` as `test1` .

Now, if I remove the order by clause from both queries, the problem goes away and transaction 2 gets completed even when transaction 1 is never committed. I tried some Googling around this and found similar issue posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694658/how-many-rows-will-be-locked-by-select-order-by-xxx-limit-1-for-update). As per the accepted answer, setting the parameters `binlog_format` to `row` and `tx_isolation` to `read-committed` is supposed to solve it. But even after setting these parameters, it's not getting solved for me.

One thing to note is both the columns in the where clause are part of an index and I have confirmed using `explain` clause that the query is using the same index. Please suggest how this can be solved. The Mysql version is '5.7.12' as per `select version()` query.

Output for show create table -

```
'CREATE TABLE `model_requests` (
  `id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `client_id` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `model_request_status` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `model_request_execution_status` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `model_function_name` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `model_function_sub_type` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `model_function_version` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `archetype_name` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `request_user` varchar(512) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `priority` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mpu_retry_total` int(11) DEFAULT ''0'',
  `client_retry_total` int(11) DEFAULT ''0'',
  `max_retry_client_count` int(11) DEFAULT ''1'',
  `max_retry_mpu_count` int(11) DEFAULT ''1'',
  `mpu_ack_timeout` bigint(20) DEFAULT ''10'',
  `client_ack_timeout` bigint(20) DEFAULT ''10'',
  `client_name` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `sub_type_version` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT ''1.0'',
  `is_synchronous` tinyint(4) DEFAULT ''0'',
  `mpu_expiry_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_expiry_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `routing_key` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  KEY `index_maas_request_id` (`id`),
  KEY `index_model_requests_status_arch_type_priority_created_at` (`model_request_status`,`archetype_name`,`priority`,`created_at`),
  KEY `index_model_requests_status_arch_type_rkey_priority_created_at` (`model_request_status`,`archetype_name`,`routing_key`,`priority`,`created_at`),
  KEY `index_model_requests_status_client_priority_created_at` (`priority`,`created_at`,`client_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
/*!50500 PARTITION BY LIST  COLUMNS(model_request_status)
SUBPARTITION BY KEY (routing_key)
SUBPARTITIONS 5
(PARTITION cancelled VALUES IN (''CANCELLED'') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION completed VALUES IN (''COMPLETED'') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION in_progress VALUES IN (''IN_PROGRESS'') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION notified_cancelled VALUES IN (''NOTIFIED_CANCELLED'') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION queued VALUES IN (''QUEUED'') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION notified VALUES IN (''NOTIFIED'') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION acknoweleded VALUES IN (''ACKNOWLEDGED'') ENGINE = InnoDB) */'
```

Comment: I don't see an order by clause?

Comment: I had forgotten adding it. Added now

Comment: Please edit your question to show (as text) output of `show create table maas.model_requests` and `select version()`

Comment: I have added both

Comment: so id is not supposed to be a unique key?  I'm not seeing the index with both id and model_request_status you mention; what did explain show?

Comment: note that 5.7.12 is 7 years old; you are missing many security patches and will have many publicly known vulnerabilities.  consider upgrading to 8 (or at least the newest 5.7, though 5.7 will reach end of life and no longer get security fixes in just a few months); upgrading may even resolve this issue.

Comment: Yes. Agree. But the application we are using is quite huge and upgrading mysql version will required significant amount of time

Comment: Adding the index on all the three columns (2 in search criteria and 1 in order by clause) did not solve the problem. We are thinking to handle the locks in the application manually using some identifier instead of using Mysql's locking

Comment: Show the create table with the index you tried, and the explain with that index.

Comment: You can likely upgrade to 5.7.43 without breaking anything, but read through https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/ first.   There's a decent chance it will fix your problem.