# Handle stored procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, gwt

I have a button in gwt and on each click i want that value should increase in the database. How should i do using stored procedure. Its like hitting like button and increasing the counter on the particular post. new for all this want help.

```
    public String fun()
    {
           Connection con=null;

           CallableStatement pt=null;

         try
         {

               Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
               con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/check", "root", "root");                


                pt=(CallableStatement)con.prepareCall("{call ask (1)}");

                pt.executeUpdate();

                System.out.println("2");
                         }
                con.close();
                pt.close();

        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     return""; 
}
}
```

STORED PROCEDURE:

DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `ask`(IN good int)
BEGIN
update likepost set hitlike=hitlike+1 where idlikepost=1 ;
END

TASK COMPLETED YIPEE!!!!

Comment: Have you written the stored procedure? do you have any idea about GWT RPC?

Comment: yes i have idea worked on it. but my query is not working

Comment: i have taken a table with two columns one for id and other for counter like.. I have statically given the id 1. when i executed the update query on mysql it worked properly but not in

Comment: i have passed a value from client side to server side and used the following code whats wrong? hellpppp

Comment: Why `pt.setInt(2, 1 );` is used? you have just one parameter to be set.

Comment: Please have a look at [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: i told u na that i have given static id.

Comment: have a look at [Increment a database field by 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762851/increment-a-database-field-by-1)

Comment: my main task is to increment the value in db on button click like we click on like of fb and other sites

Comment: you have one `?` in your query it means you can call `setInt()` just single time.

Comment: initially for the basic stage i jst want the counter to incement in db for 1 post or u can say one particular id.

Comment: first? for set and  other for where condition wts wrong in that

Comment: pt=con.prepareStatement("Update dataa set FirstName=?, LastName=?, CollegeName=?,SchoolName=? where UserId=?");
          pt.setString(1,fnme1);
          pt.setString(2,lnme1);
          pt.setString(3,clgn1);
          pt.setString(4,scn1);
          pt.setInt(5,id);

Comment: what happen do you think its still wrong its my working code

Comment: you have edited you post. now its correct `two ?`

Comment: `hitlike` will be 2 and `idlikepost` will be 1. Try with `con.commit();` in the end before `con.close()`

Comment: yup help me that how should i increment value in db on button click

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Comment: nops but its goin onFailure()

Comment: i tried using stored procedure also.. i am sending u that

Comment: Exception caught: com.client.GreetingService_Proxy.fun(Lcom/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/AsyncCallback;)V

Comment: after using stored procedure

Comment: Sorry exception is too short to analyze it. please share full stack trace.

Comment: send me ur mail id i'll send u you whole code than u can analyze my mistake if u have tym..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51808/discussion-between-priya-and-braj)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First of all replace `Window.alert("hello");` with `e.printStackTrace()` to watch the logs.**

There is no meaning of `Window.alert("hello");` at server side code.