# Increment existing database value to use it as the value for a new record

Tags: mysql, max

I have a table holding items with **item_order** column as non-nullable INT.

When I create a new item I need the highest **item_order** existing in  the table, so I can increment it and insert new record. Below an **abstract** example of what I mean:

```
INSERT INTO item (name, item_order)
VALUES ('New Item', (SELECT MAX(item_order) FROM item AS item_order) + 1)
```

I assume this is crazy talk :) How do I achieve what I need?

**UPDATE:**

I found this useful: [Increment a database field by 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762851/increment-a-database-field-by-1)

Can I then use `SELECT MAX(item_order) + 1` as I showed above, as `VALUES` argument?

Answer (score 0):

change item_order to an AUTO_INCREMENT column.

```
ALTER TABLE `item` 
CHANGE COLUMN `item_order` `item_order` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

This assumes that you've made it your primary key, otherwise if you really want to do it that way then you can do.

```
SET @nextItemOrder = IFNULL((SELECT MAX(item_order) FROM item AS item_order),0) + 1;
INSERT INTO item (name, item_order)
VALUES ('New Item', @nextItemOrder);
```

Comment: Can't do that. The **item_order** is changable. Admin sets the order, it cannot be auto-incremented.