# modify an existing column with basic operations

Tags: sql

I'm going to implement this function!

```
+-----+-----+
|name | age |
+-----+-----+
|Dong | 19  |
|Dung | 25  |
+-----+-----+
```

I want to increase column "age" by one like this:

```
+-----+-----+
|name | age |
+-----+-----+
|Dong | 20  |
|Dung | 26  |
+-----+-----+
```

pls help me solutions!!

There were twos solution which I thought:
1) using UPDATE sqlCommand. 
    update x set a = a + 1 where a = "age"

2) create new column = old column + 1 then replace old column by new one.

Comment: Have you tried something? You only need a simple query for this. Just use `+` operator in your query.

Comment: There were twos solution which I thought:                                                                                       
1) using UPDATE sqlCommand
2) create new column = old column + 1 then replace old column by new one.

Comment: @NguyễnTrọngĐông check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/2762851/1673391

Comment: Write it in your question, so the other people can help you..

Answer (score 3):

2 possible answer.

1. Do you want to increase the age permanently? If yes, just update the data.

   ```
   update tbl1 set age = age + 1;
   ```
2. If you only want show the age + 1 when you view the data:

   ```
   select name, age + 1 as age from tbl
   ```