# Add numerical value to every numerical value of a column mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a database with a **rate** column with numerical data. I would like to update the data in this column by adding 20 to each.

I am trying,

```
UPDATE 'refinance' SET 'rate' = rate + 20
```

I get a syntax error when I simulate this query :

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''refinance' SET 'rate' = rate + 20' at line 1

Thanks for the input on this.
Eric

Comment: What is the error? And your real table name?

Comment: There is no error in the query bro. So mention your error too.
"table" is a keyword in mysql. Is your table_name "table"?

Comment: The table name is "refinance"

Comment: the error is: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: you will get this error if you use the mysql reserved words etc:table,from etc..

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add any errors **in** your question so that it is complete as is.

Comment: Are you executing 2 queries at once? The error indicates that there is a problem right before your actual query or at the first character.

Comment: No I am just using this one update command.  The column format is decimal(11,2) would that have any impact on this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762851/increment-a-database-field-by-1

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @mawg but i do not want just one row so I don't want to use the where clause to target and id I want to update every value in every row of the column by a value of 20

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the update table syntax, you need to specify the tablename not table keyword.

```
UPDATE refinance SET rate = rate + 20;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Comment: Yes I am using the actual table name in the query

Comment: then you please update the exact query which you have tried and error in the question

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out this query works after all, **I only get the error when I press the "Simulate Query" button in phpMyAdmin** when I hit the "go" button it processes without error.

I am relatively new to sql so not sure why this would be the case or what the benefit of simulation is if it is not a representation of the actual syntax.  Thanks to everyone for the input and time.

Eric