# Update a column in a mySQL data base by 1

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL database with 250 rows. I inserted a column filled with 0's. I updated the first rows 11 rows to be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 & 11. The rest of the rows are still 0's.

How would I go about updating rows 11-250 to go from 0 to each of the relevant row value.

thank you!

Comment: relevant value as in matching the row number? how do you define first and second row? using primary key or something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increment a database field by 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762851/increment-a-database-field-by-1)

Comment: @AlfredoRamirezJr. it does not. im looking to update each value by 1 so row 210, the value is = 210

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: " im looking to update each value by 1"  so row 210 did have the value 0 (as per your question) How would it become 210 ?  Incrementing it by 1 does set it to `1`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approach (which i can think of) to this problem. You can either using window function alternatively, you can use variable.

Assuming you have the following test table:

```
create table salsa (id int, name varchar(255), new_column int);

insert into salsa values
    (1, 'a', 0),
    (2, 'b', 0),
    (4, 'c', 0),
    (3, 'e', 0),
    (9, 'f', 0);
```

### Using Variable

The variable one is pretty straight forward. Though you have less control over which one first. This part is adapted from [row_number() in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql).

```
with
    my_ranking as (
      select s.*,
            @rownum := @rownum + 1 as _rank
     from salsa s,
          (select @rownum := 0) r
   )
update salsa as s1
   set new_column = (
     select _rank
     from my_ranking as s2
     where s1.id = s2.id
     limit 1
   );
```

The `@rownum` variable is used to keep track the current rank of the row.

See fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/Jmn5x34WXaBJq7oyemtXp/0

### Using Window Function

The [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html) comes with `rank()` which we will use this time. It require at least mysql version 8 to use.

```
with
   my_ranking as (
     select *,
            rank() over(order by id) as _rank
     from salsa
   )
update salsa as s1
   set new_column = (
     select _rank
     from my_ranking as s2
     where s1.id = s2.id
     limit 1
   );
```

The reason i'm asking for point of reference how to rank the rows is that, the `rank()` need to be partitioned to work otherwise everyone is rank 1. The important part is the:

```
rank() over(order by id) as _rank
```

To determine the "position" of the row, you could use `id` or other column as you needed.

See fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nwLv9R7weQt4e5RhUbgaUL/0

Note:

- Both query above need mysql 8 given I used [CTE (Common Table Expression)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) because I'm too lazy to write them as subqueries.
- There might be better query out there, think of this as duct tape or something.

Answer (score 0):

If a classic version (prior to 8.0) is being used, which does not support CTE and window functions, we have to find a workaround. To resolve the issue, we can use the user variable trick. Below are the complete steps to demonstrate it.

```
drop table if exists test;
create table test(id int primary key auto_increment, num int default 0);
delimiter //
drop procedure if exists makerows//
-- let's create a procedure to generate necessary rows.
create procedure makerows()
begin
declare c int default 1;

lp:loop
if c>250 then
leave lp;
end if;

if c<=11 then
insert test values(default,c);
else insert test (id) values(default);
end if;
set c=c+1;
end loop lp;

end//
delimiter ;
call makerows; -- now we have the test table with the id from 1 to 250 and the num from 1 to 11 with the rest being 0

-- here is the user variable trick to generate row id as required. Note we set the initial @row_id to -1 so we can calculate the first @row_id to be 0 for the first row (id=11).
select id ,@row_id:=@row_id+1 as row_id 
from test,(select @row_id:=-1) t 
where id>=11 order by id ;

-- the query above is used to get a derived table which shall be joined to the base table, so we can update the required num column 
update test t1 
join
(select id ,@row_id:=@row_id+1 as row_id 
from test,(select @row_id:=-1) t 
where id>=11 order by id) t2 
on t1.id=t2.id
set t1.num=t2.row_id
;

-- now we have the test table in which the id from 11 to 250 have the num column values from 0 to 239
select * from test;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a user-defined variable (`@rownumber` for example) to increment a value of `1`.

```
UPDATE your_table
SET your_column = (@rownumber := 1 + @rownumber)
WHERE 0 = (@rownumber := 0)
```

**Result:**

```
| Input | Output |
|-------|--------|
| 1     | 1      |
| 2     | 2      |
| 3     | 3      |
| 4     | 4      |
| 5     | 5      |
| 6     | 6      |
| 7     | 7      |
| 8     | 8      |
| 9     | 9      |
| 10    | 10     |
| 11    | 11     |
| ...   | ...    |
| 0     | 245    |
| 0     | 246    |
| 0     | 247    |
| 0     | 248    |
| 0     | 249    |
| 0     | 250    |
```

**Demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/4I7v6cWN).**